# change ImageView in only one instance

Tags: java, android, widget, imageview

I'm making an application with a widget.
the widget contains ImageView, when i click on it, it going to change the Image in ImageView.

But when I make multiple instances, and click on one of them, the image changes in all instances

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class MyWidgetProviderSimple extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String ACTION_CLICK = "ACTION_CLICK";
    public static String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {

        // Get all ids
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
                MyWidgetProviderSimple.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {

            updateAppWidget (context, appWidgetManager, widgetId, allWidgetIds);

        }
    }

    private void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int widgetId, int [] allWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_start);

        Log.w("-widgetId:", String.valueOf(widgetId));


        if (getWidgetValue(context, widgetId) == -1)
        {
            setWidgetValue(context, widgetId, 0);
        }

        // Set the text to the view with the id R.id.update
        // instead of -1
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widgetImageView, getImageToSet(context, widgetId));

        // Register an onClickListener
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProviderSimple.class);

        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetImageView, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);



    }
    public int getImageToSet(Context context, int widgetId) {
        int value = getWidgetValue (context, widgetId);
        Log.w("-- getImageToSet:", String.valueOf(widgetId));

        if (value == -1) {
            Log.d("-- couldn't find", String.valueOf(widgetId));
            return -1;
        }


        if (value == 5)
        {
            value = 0;
        }

        //TODO: must be replaced by Array list
        int drawables = R.drawable.uui1 + value;

        value++;

        setWidgetValue(context, widgetId, value);

        return drawables;
    }

    public static void setWidgetValue(Context context, int appWidgetId, int value) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putInt(String.valueOf(appWidgetId), value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static int getWidgetValue(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        return prefs.getInt(String.valueOf(appWidgetId), -1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        if( appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID )
        {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The method updateAppWidget(ComponentName provider, RemoteViews views) sets the RemoteViews to use for all AppWidget instances for the supplied AppWidget provider.

You want to use this method: updateAppWidget(int appWidgetId, RemoteViews views) which set the RemoteViews to use for the specified appWidgetId.

To do this you will need to keep track of the widget's id"

check the rest of the answer here:
[multiple instances of widget with separated working clickable ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174386/multiple-instances-of-widget-with-separated-working-clickable-imageview)